# Смена иконки после закрепления программы на панели задач

Tags: c++, mfc

Есть функция, которая меняет иконку каждую секунду:

```
if(Seconds % 2)
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIconW(IDR_MAINFRAME);
else
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIconW(IDI_ICON_CONNECTED);
SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);
```

Работает отлично, до тех пор пока не **закрепить программу на панели задач**. После закрепления иконка не изменяется. Как возможно решить эту проблему?